# Visual studio 2013: cannot see drop down to start debugging with any browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

Supposedly with visual studio 2013 I can choose to start debugging my asp.net web app with any browser
as the following post/image suggests:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CrossBrowserDebuggingIntegratedIntoVisualStudioWithBrowserStack.aspx

[image]

However in my visual studio 2013 (Update 3), I don't see that drop down. There is only the play button.

How do I get the drop down to appear?

note: If I right click on a .cshtml page then I get the "Browser with" option, but that's not what I'm after...

Thanks

Comment: See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df5x06h3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can see Debug drop down in your screen shot, next to "Google Chrome"

Comment: @AtifMahmood he knows that, but he doesn't get the dropdown.

Answer (score 12):

This can happen when you do not have a "StartUp Project" set.

Right click your project from the Solution Explorer on the right pane and select "Set as StartUp project".

Comment: I was going to suggest this also ... as simple a thing as not having your web project be your start-up project causes an annoying side-effect: you are no longer able to choose which browser runs the project.

Answer (score 5):

It took me forever to find this as well. I changed my name recently and had to blow away my old profile at work, I exported my VS settings before doing this but alas, something went wrong on import and I was left to set up VS to my liking from scratch...again.

Anyhow, I tried making sure my Startup Project was set and still nothing showed so Lord Taver's answer didn't work for me. I continued to hunt for this and finally found how to get it back and thought I'd share with the community.

1. If you've already customized your tool bars this may not be in exactly the same place but should still be easy to figure out. In the tool bar, with the grouping of icons that contain the Save and Save All buttons, click the drop down that allows you to customize the buttons for that section.
   [image: Image for step 1]
2. Hover over the "Add or Remove Buttons" option in the drop down which produces a menu. I wish I could get my screen shot to work with the menu open but it won't work with me today. The options on this menu start with Navigate Backward.

3.To get the option to select your browser from the drop down, enable the "Debug Target" (outlined in bright green) option. I also chose to enable the "Browser Link" (outlined in aqua) icon which allows you to refresh the browsers linked to VS and pull up the Browser Link Dashboard if desired.

[image: Here are the buttons after adding them back]

This finally got me what I was looking for the whole time but it was definitely a struggle. Aren't very many helpful tips out there on retrieving this if it's lost. Hope this helps you even though it's months after your question.

Comment: I upgraded to vs 2015 so i'm not able to verify this answer but i'll vote it up.

Comment: +1 mine was set to "Start Debug Target" which just had the green play button with no drop down to select the target.

Comment: I spent ages trying to add Debug Target to my custom toolbar, but there seems to be no way as it never shows Debug Target in the list of commands you can add to a custom bar (unless that's just a glitch on my box). Solution: re-add Standard toolbar, and delete all its commands except Debug Target, so it can sit alongside custom toolbar at least.

Answer (score 2):

This drop down is referred to as Browser Link.

"Browser Link is a new feature in Visual Studio 2013 that creates a communication channel between the development environment and one or more web browsers. You can use Browser Link to refresh your web application in several browsers at once, which is useful for cross-browser testing." - [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link)

In there you can also find a very decent Overview and how to enable and disable Browser Link.

You can also [click here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) for additional information and help.

Comment: I had a look at those pages but I couldn't find anything that showed how to get the browser drop down...